# How to stop while loop when it reaches last page

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape product name and its links from amazon root links

root1.csv:
https://www.amazon.com.au/s/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_p_85_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A4851510051%2Cp_4%3AThe+Gro+Company%2Cp_6%3AANEGB3WVEVKZB%2Cp_85%3A5444100051&bbn=4851510051&ie=UTF8&qid=1530074038&rnid=5444099051
https://www.amazon.com.au/s/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_p_6_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A4851510051%2Cp_4%3AES+Kids%2Cp_85%3A5444100051%2Cp_6%3AANEGB3WVEVKZB&bbn=4851510051&ie=UTF8&qid=1530074169&rnid=4910514051

My script is: below

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from io import StringIO
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import csv
import time
import os
data = open("input/root1.csv", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()
dataFile = StringIO(data)
csvReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
for row in csvReader:
    data = []
    myurl = row[0]
    f = open('output/product_links1.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    source_code = requests.get(myurl)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')
    agent = {'User-Agent': 'Magic Browser'}
    req1 = requests.get(myurl, headers=agent)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req1.content, "html.parser")
    headers = {
        # 'cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.1576298877.1530030143; _gid=GA1.3.898834.1530030143; __lc.visitor_id.8904714=S1530030142.7515ce042a; sid_customer_0b4ee=8afef780e801184c0fb0e6eb689b52ca-1-C; roadblocked_at=1530030165529; nocache=1; lc_sso8904714=1530112813205; lc_window_state=minimized',
        'accept-encoding': 'text */*',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36',
        'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'referer': 'https://onlinelighting.com.au/lr-3704-adjustable-spot-light-rod-suspension-remote-transformer-43cm.html',
        'authority': 'onlinelighting.com.au',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }
    agent1 = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405'}
    req = requests.get(myurl, headers=headers)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
    #data.append(row[0])
    #print(soup)
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:/Mine/Python/geckodriver.exe')
    #driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:/Users/sk00425103/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs')
    driver.get(myurl)
    src = driver.page_source
    parser = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    time.sleep(2)
    for head in parser.findAll('li', {"class": "s-result-item"}):
        for name in head.findAll('a', {"class": "s-access-detail-page"}):
            link0 = name.get("href")
            for name1 in name.findAll('h2'):
                title = name1.text
                data = [link0, title]
                print(data)
                writer.writerow(data)

    while True:
        nextpage = driver.find_element_by_id("pagnNextString")
        nextpage.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        src1 = driver.page_source
        parser1 = BeautifulSoup(src1, "lxml")
        time.sleep(2)
        for nx_head in parser1.findAll('li', {"class": "s-result-item"}):
            for nx_name in nx_head.findAll('a', {"class": "s-access-detail-page"}):
                nx_link0 = nx_name.get("href")
                for nx_name1 in nx_name.findAll('h2'):
                    nx_title = nx_name1.text
                    data = [nx_link0, nx_title]
                    print(data)
                    writer.writerow(data)
        time.sleep(2)
```

I want to stop the while loop when it reaches last page(NextPage link is disabled) and it will take next root link from root1.csv to crawl

Please help on this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you are using, but can't you use a for loop instead of while True to only go through all the links in a list?

Comment: No. Each link is having multiple pages. For example, first link having 10 pages. When it reaches 10th page, it keeps on appending 10th page data into output. I want to break while loop on that 10th page and take next URL from root1.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a stopping flag to your `while True` loop.

E.g.

```
cont = True
while cont:
  # Do a lot of stuff
  if last_page(): cont = False
```

If you don't best loops too much, you can also use `break`. That is 
possible in my pseudocode above, but if you'd need the check in a nested loop, `break` applies to the inner loop only and [Python does not have labeled loops to allow labeled break/continue](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/).

Usually, I would recommend to clean up and refactor your code to something clean like this rather than nesting loops too much:

```
nextURL = firstURL
while nextURL:
  nextURL = processNextPage(nextURL)
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that.

Comment: There is a html list as below

<li>hello<li>
<li>hello1<li>
<li>hello2<li>

I want to join all li values into a variable like:

var1= hello hello1 hello2

My code is overwritten all li values and return only hello2

            for desc in soup1.findAll('div', {"id": "feature-bullets"}):
                for desc1 in desc.findAll('ul'):
                    for desc2 in desc1.findAll('li'):
                        for i in desc2:
                            desc3 = i.text
                            final_desc = " ". join(desc3)

Please help on this

Comment: Use an array to collect things. I'm not giving you a programming class here.

Comment: I tried with adding into array. It stores the last li value only

Please help

Comment: Try appending to an array. And get a tutorial. Don't expect me to mind-read what is on your screen...